# finding the subset with the most significant correlation between two variables

Tags: r, regression, correlation

I have a number of cases with two correlated variables.

```
library(MASS)
n <- 1000
e.cor <- matrix(0.4, 2, 2)
diag(e.cor) <- 1
e <- mvrnorm(n, c(0,0), e.cor)
e<-as.data.frame(e)
colnames(e) <- c('x', 'y')

fit<-lm(x ~ y, data = e)
summary(fit)
```

How can I drop cases from e to maximize the significance of the model.

Comment: It's not hard to drop points that will make the correlation high and the p-value low -- but to what purpose?

Comment: I want to find the minimum of the p-values by dropping points. If I started to drop the worst fitting points I could e.g get the following table of r and n , resulting in the following p values. So the subgroup would contain cc.300 points, because that's where p is the lowest. Could you suggest a method for this?

r        n             p
0.4 1000 8.26E-41
0.5 800        3.08E-54
0.6 600        2.44E-64
0.7 400        6.56E-67
0.8 200        1.21E-53

Comment: "*I want to find the minimum of the p-values by dropping points*" -- yes, this was already clear. ***WHY*** do you want to do that? What could doing this possibly gain you? (please understand that the p-value itself will be utterly meaningless).

Comment: 1. I would like to see how stable the regression coefficients remain during the process. 2. I would like to compare this "most predictable" group with the whole population along other variables to see if there is anything special about them.

Comment: I don't see what real value there can be in this exercise. Note that the best subset of size m and the best subset of size m-1 might not have any points in common.